# How to get the absolute URL after creating an object in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get the URL to the object that was just created:

```
code = HttpStatusCode.Created;
String location = Url.Route("ApiRoute", new {@id = bp.Id, @controller = "ProfileController" });
Response.AppendHeader("Location", location);
```

Here the Route

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But it seems to have changed from MVC3 to MVC4.

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Url.RouteUrl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492238.aspx) method which accepts a `protocol` parameter. This returns a fully qualified url.

```
// Formatted for readability
code = HttpStatusCode.Created;
String location = Url.Route(
  "ApiRoute", 
  new {@id = bp.Id, @controller = "ProfileController" }, 
  "http"
);
Response.AppendHeader("Location", location);
```

Comment: Ok. So the example you provided, though, still shows Route. That should be RouteUrl then? Thx! :)

Comment: I just tried it out and Url.RouteUrl returns a null with the information you see there. Also, I added the Route to my original post.